# How to change post from published to draft according to date

Tags: date, post

I have set the code below to turn custom post types (jobs) from published to draft if the application closing date has surpassed. This uses the custom field 'application_date'. Everything from hat I can see is correct. I have updated WP date to d-m-Y and the custom field it set to input and display as d-m-Y. Any ideas why this won't work?

This is the code used:

```
// Set job adverts to draft on application date
function update_job_status_based_on_date() {
    // Get the current date
    $current_date = date('d-m-Y');

    // Query the custom post type
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'jobs',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    // Loop through the posts
    if ($query->have_posts()) {
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();

            // Get the custom date field value
            $group_field_values = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'group_64a297389576b', true);
            $custom_date = isset($group_field_values['application_date']) ? $group_field_values['application_date'] : '';

            // Compare the custom date with the current date
            if ($custom_date <= $current_date) {
                // Update the post status to draft
                $post_data = array(
                    'ID' => get_the_ID(),
                    'post_status' => 'draft',
                    'post_author' => get_the_author_ID(),
                );
                wp_update_post($post_data);
            }
        }

        // Reset the post data
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}

// Schedule the function to run daily
add_action('init', 'schedule_job_status_update');
function schedule_job_status_update() {
    if (!wp_next_scheduled('update_job_status_hook')) {
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'update_job_status_hook');
    }
}

// Call the scheduling function
schedule_job_status_update();
add_action('update_job_status_hook', 'update_job_status_based_on_date');
```